# How to make fixed-data-table React fixed columns to both left and right side?

Tags: reactjs

I'm looking for a way to make same below with fixed-data-table React

> https://datatables.net/extensions/fixedcolumns/examples/initialisation/left_right_columns.html
>   Left and right fixed columns

But in API of fixed-data-table, it seems doesn't support this feature.
Anyidea?

Comment: https://facebook.github.io/fixed-data-table/api-column.html `fixed` prop?

Comment: with more than 2 columns have `fixed={true}` props, the columns will be fixed to left side of table. Not "both left and right fixed columns"

Comment: Looks like fixed-data-table doesn't support what you want to see.